# postgres db query . How to use single quote and double quote and how to get the join working

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using postgresdb and I ran into an issue running queries using pdAdmin...

Here are the tables that I have :
user table

[image]

There is a transaction table like this.
[image]

Here are the queries that I am looking for.

1. How to join the two table to get the join result on 'user.id' and 'transaction.partnerUserId' table.. when I am running it , I am not getting any result and there is the single quote and double quote confustion too..

anybody can help with the query...

Comment: You forgot to post your query. Single quotes are used to quote string data while double quotes are used to quote table and/or column names.

Comment: select "firstName", amount from "user" 
join "transaction"  
on 'user.id' = 'transaction.partnerUserId'

Comment: the above query returned no raw. in fact all the rows are matching the condition but no result.

Comment: Try this : `select "firstName", amount from "user" join transaction on "user".id = transaction."partnerUserId ;` You only have to double quote identifiers to preserve mixed case or  all upper case and for reserved words e.g. "user". For reserved words see [Reserved](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). The fields you are comparing don't need to be single quoted. For more information see [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Thanks man.. that was the reason.. it works now.. can you reply to my question so that I can upvote the answer...  in case if you have more idea about the naming conventions in the db world , elaborate that as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the query as:

```
select "firstName", amount from "user" join transaction on "user".id = transaction."partnerUserId ;
```

Identifiers need to be double quoted if they are a reserved word or some form of "MixedCase" or "UPPERCASE", per documentation here [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). **NOTE**, this is for Postgres which works opposite the SQL standard in lower casing unquoted identifiers instead of upper casing them. I personally use lower case identifiers with underscores where necessary.